# How do I specify matching options in Swift regular expression literal?

Tags: swift, regex

With new literal syntax for Swift regular expressions it remains unclear how can I add search flags to it?

```swift
let regex = /^foo/mi // Cannot find 'mi' in scope error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift regex literal parser doesn't have expression-wide matching options, but you can specify any options inline at very beginning of the pattern to achieve the same effect:

```swift
let regex = /(?mi)^foo/
```